# Pre-fill Slack message in web interface

Tags: slack

Is there a URL parameter or other means to pre-populate the message field when navigating to a Slack channel in Slack's web interface?

That is, a user would click on a link to a Slack channel in their browser, and on arriving at the linked page would have part of their message already written, but not sent.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with the [Slack API](https://api.slack.com/docs/interactive-message-field-guide), they offer some "confirmation fields" codes to request user confirmation before taking certain action.

This could apply to your case, by getting a certain piece of text ready but requiring an OK before actually sending that over the chat.

```
"confirm": {
    "title": "Are you sure?",
    "text": "Wouldn't you prefer a good game of chess?",
    "ok_text": "Yes",
    "dismiss_text": "No"
}
```

> Protect users from destructive actions or particularly distinguished decisions by asking them to confirm their button click one more time. Use confirmation dialogs with care.
>
> These fields should be presented as a JSON hash buried deep within the confirm field of an action within the actions array that's also part of an attachment that's inside the attachments array field of a message.